# Get several resutls from one table in a query using recursive

Tags: oracle

I want to do this in a recursive query. I tried my best to make the question clear If you have any questiong ill answer quickly

I have 4 test procedures : PRC_TEST1 , PRC_TEST2, PRC_TEST3 , prc_test4

Inside of PRC_TEST1 it is executing PRC_TEST2 ... and PRC_TEST2 is executing prc_test3. and prc_test3 is executing prc_test4

```
create or replace procedure prc_test1
as

begin
prc_test2();
end;
/

create or replace procedure prc_test2
as

begin
prc_test3();
end;
/

create or replace procedure prc_test3
as

begin
prc_test4();
end;
/

create or replace procedure prc_test4
as

begin
null;
end;
/
```

**I want to know from a recursive query what are prc_test2 is exeucting and at the same time I want to know the procedure is referenced to .. the below example queries will explain my result.**

in the below queries I am checking to where prc_test2 is refering.

> select **referenced_name** from user_dependencies where name ='PRC_TEST2'

the first query will give me prc_test3 , becuase PRC_test2 is executing prc_test3
then I check if prc_test3 is executing a procedure

> select **referenced_name** from user_dependencies where name ='PRC_TEST3'

and ofcourse the result will be prc_test4

at the same time I want to know if there are procedures executing prc_test2 .. by a query I can know that

> select **name**  from user_dependencies where referenced_name='PRC_TEST2'

Ill get the result prc_test1 , then I make sure if there a procedure calling prc_test1

> select **name**  from user_dependencies where referenced_name='PRC_TEST1'
>   we will have no results.

I want a query (or a procedure) that can give me all the results of the above query in ONE query

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I fixed it , it should be referenced_name . anyway is there a query or a procedure to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one of the approaches(probably can be optimized) you can do the following.

Here are our 4 test procedures:

```
create or replace procedure proc4
as
begin
  null;
end;
/
create or replace procedure proc3
as
begin
  proc4;
end;
/
create or replace procedure proc2
as
begin
  proc3;
end;
/
create or replace procedure proc1
as
begin
  proc2;
end;
/
```

And the dependency tree:

```
with dependencies(d_name, d_referenced_name) as(
  select nvl(d1.name, d2.referenced_name)
       , d1.referenced_name
   from user_dependencies d1
        full join user_dependencies d2
          on (d1.name = d2.referenced_name)
  where d1.type = 'PROCEDURE'
     or d2.type = 'PROCEDURE'
)
select concat( lpad('-', 3*level, '-')
             , d.d_name) as res 
  from dependencies d 
start with d.d_name = 'PROC1'
connect by d.d_name = prior d.d_referenced_name
```

Result:

```
RES
------------------
---PROC1
------PROC2
---------PROC3
------------PROC4
```

[**SQLFiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be5cc/1)

Comment: +1 `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(d.d_name,'-')` could also be a choice!

Answer (score 1):

I found something similar to this

```
SELECT    
             t2.name AS parent_name,
             t1.name, 
             t1.REFERENCED_NAME as calling_to
         --  t2.REFERENCED_NAME AS p_reference
      FROM user_dependencies t1
 LEFT JOIN user_dependencies t2 ON t1.name = T2.REFERENCED_NAME
START WITH t1.name = 'PRC_TEST2' 
CONNECT BY PRIOR t1.NAME = T1.REFERENCED_NAME
```